# PID Controller library

Tags: c++, library, arduino

I'm trying to implement a PID without floating point operations on a micro controller. I appreciate all feedback I can get.

Header file:

```
#ifndef BRUSHPID_H
#define BRUSHPID_H

#if defined(ARDUINO) && (ARDUINO >= 100) // Arduino Library
#include "Arduino.h"
#else
#include "WProgram.h"
#endif


#define KU_CONSTANT 2

#define DT  100         //  in milliseconds, descrete time step size chose to be 0.1[s]=100[ms]
#define PERIOD 6000     //  in milliseconds, measured as 6[s]=6000[ms]


// Ziegler Algorithem Constants
#define ZIEGLER_P 0
#define ZIEGLER_PI 1
#define ZIEGLER_CLASSIC_PID 2
#define ZIEGLER_PESSEN_INTEGAL_RULE 3
#define ZIEGLER_SOME_OVERSHOOT 4
#define ZIEGLER_NO_OVERSHOOT 5

// Tuning Type
#define TUNING_TYPE ZIEGLER_P

// bit extension to avoid float operations
#define LONG_SHIFT 10


class BrushPID{
private:
    unsigned long p;
    unsigned long i;
    unsigned long d;
    signed long lCurrentError;
    signed long lLastError;
    signed long lTotalError;
    signed long lMaxError;
    signed long lMaxTotalError;
    signed long caclulateNextOutput(void);
    unsigned long ulLastTimeStamp;
    void zieglerNicholasTuning(signed int iTuningMethod);
    void resetTotalError(void);
public:
    BrushPID(void);
    ~BrushPID(void);
    signed long getNextOutput(signed long *newError);
};



#endif BRUSHPID_H
```

Source File:

```
#include "BrushPID.h"
#include "../BrushCommon/BrushCommon.h"


BrushPID::BrushPID(void) {

    // init local object data
    this->lCurrentError=0;
    this->lLastError=0;
    this->lTotalError=0;
    this->ulLastTimeStamp=millis(); // timestamp since arduino boot in milliseconds
    this->p=KU_CONSTANT;
    this->i=0;
    this->d=0;

    //init PID paramaters according to chosen tuning type
    this->zieglerNicholasTuning(TUNING_TYPE);

    // calculate overflow boundry
    this->lMaxTotalError=MAX_SIGNED_LONG-MAX_SIGNED_LONG/(max(this->i*DT,1)); // max to prevent division by 0
    this->lMaxError=MAX_SIGNED_LONG-MAX_SIGNED_LONG/(max(max(this->p,this->d),1)); 
}

// destructor
BrushPID::~BrushPID(void) {
    //nothing to do     
}

// next step of discrete PID 
long BrushPID::getNextOutput(long *newError){

    //prevent overflows
    if(lMaxTotalError<abs(this->lTotalError)) this->resetTotalError();
    if(lMaxError<abs(*newError)) *newError=this->lLastError;

    //check if DT has passed, by comparing current to last registered time stamp
    while((millis()-this->ulLastTimeStamp)<DT);
    //set new timestamp
    this->ulLastTimeStamp=millis();


    this->lLastError=this->lCurrentError;
    this->lCurrentError=*newError;
    this->lTotalError+=*newError*DT;
    return caclulateNextOutput();
}

long BrushPID::caclulateNextOutput(void){
    return (this->p*this->lCurrentError+this->i*this->lTotalError+this->d*(this->lCurrentError-this->lLastError)/DT)>>LONG_SHIFT;
}


/* ****
* Setting PID Parameter according to  Ziegler-Nicholas tuning Method
* Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method
****/
void BrushPID::zieglerNicholasTuning(int iTuningMethod=ZIEGLER_P){

    unsigned long shifted_constant=KU_CONSTANT<<LONG_SHIFT;

    switch(iTuningMethod){
        case(ZIEGLER_P):
            this->p=shifted_constant>>1;
            this->i=0;
            this->d=0;
            break;
        case(ZIEGLER_PI):
            this->p=(shifted_constant*22)/10;
            this->i=(this->p*10)/12/max(PERIOD,1);
            this->d=0;
            break;
        case(ZIEGLER_CLASSIC_PID):
            this->p=(shifted_constant*6)/10;
            this->i=2*this->p/max(PERIOD,1);
            this->d=(this->p*PERIOD)>>3;
            break; 
        case(ZIEGLER_PESSEN_INTEGAL_RULE):
            this->p=(shifted_constant*7)/10;
            this->i=(shifted_constant<<1);
            this->d=(shifted_constant*15)/100;
        default:
            this->p=shifted_constant;
            this->i=0;
            this->d=0;
    }

}

void BrushPID::resetTotalError(){
    this->lTotalError=0;
}
```

Comment: I personally find all this `this->` business visually distracting.  If you're coding in an IDE that can't highlight class members in a different color, I find that a simple leading underscore (naming convention) is enough to call out member data.  I know this is a somewhat religious point, though.

Comment: @Nate Agreed, except prefer trailing underscores, not leading underscores. *Each name that contains a double underscore __ or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter is reserved to the implementation for any use.* - It's easy to forget this and get it wrong (I have a number of times in recent memory). Basically, use a simple rule: no `__` anywhere, and don't start anything with `_`.

Comment: @Yuushi, I find it extremely difficult to get that wrong.  Typing an underscore is already relatively difficult.  Typing two in a row is a mistake I've never made in about 17 years of coding.  You shouldn't be referencing "the implementation's" variables anyway (the ones that start with `__`), so there should be no confusion.  If your code had a mixture of variables starting with `__`, and `_`, then there would be a source of confusion.  But, you should **only** have ones starting with `_` (single) in **application layer** code.  Systems programmers would have different coding standards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know nothing of PID controllers, so I'll restrict comments to the code itself.

### Comments on the header:

- A `#endif` doesn't take a tag (BRUSHPID_H)
- Use of the 'signed' keyword is unusual. Do you have a good reason for its use?
- Hungarian notation (your variable type-prefixes) is a really bad idea
- Tuning methods would be better defined as an `enum` rather than as `#defines` and a `signed int` parameter (to `zieglerNicholasTuning`).
- OVERSHOOT defines are not used.
- pass `newError` into `getNextOutput` by reference ?

### Comments of the source file:

- It is better to define the include path in the Makefile instead of the
  source file.  So the Makefile would have something like

  ```
  -I $(PROJECT)/BrushCommon/
  ```

  as a part of the compilation rule.
- Some of the code is hard to read because of a lack of spacing around
  operators (=, <, << etc) and after keywords (if, while, etc), and because of
  single-line expressions (better to use braces and multi-line). The function
  `caclulateNextOutput` is unreadable without adding spaces.
- The default tuning type should perhaps be a parameter (with default) to the
  constructor.
- `lMaxError`, `lMaxTotalError` seem to be constants.  And why use
  MAX_SIGNED_LONG when LONG_MAX is available from limits.h
- According to the Wiki reference, ZEIGLER_PI 'p' value should be (* 10 / 22),
  the ZIEGLER_PESSEN_INTEGAL_RULE 'i' value looks wrong and the
  ZIEGLER_PESSEN_INTEGAL_RULE 'd' value has a hard-coded time constant (100)
- In `zieglerNicholasTuning`, I'd call `shifted_constant` just `ku` and make
  it `const`.  But then again,... in the `BrushPID` constructor, 'p' is
  initialised to KU_CONSTANT whereas in `zieglerNicholasTuning`, KU_CONSTANT
  is shifted by `LONG_SHIFT`.  This seems wrong.  The initial, wrong, value is
  unused, but to avoid this sort of error, I would probably define KU_CONSTANT
  as `(2 << (LONG_SHIFT))` in the header
- `LONG_SHIFT` is, to me, an unhelpful name.
- `DT` better as `DELTA_T` ?
- The while loop in `getNextOutput` would be better with explicit braces :

  ```
  while ((millis() - this->ulLastTimeStamp) < DT) {
      // busy-wait
  }
  ```

  I guess you have no other way of waiting and nothing else going on that
  needs CPU time, so this is probably ok.  But **don't do it at interrupt
  level**.  In general, when there is an alternative, this sort of loop is
  best avoided.

Comment: we were taught Hungarian at uni as a uni convention, I guess you shouldn't believe everything you're taught. Thanks for the feedback, I've taken note and adjusted the library